# Writing style questions

Tags: discussion, subjective-topics

A lot of the questions here could be boiled down to writing style, e.g.

[Is it wrong to start sentences with "in which case"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138/is-it-wrong-to-start-sentences-with-in-which-case)

[What is the correct spelling of "buyer* remorse"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97/apostrophical-query-a-buyers-remorse-b-buyer-remorse-c-buyers-remorse-d)

What is the site policy on answering and voting for subjective things like style preferences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the style of the radio show, [A Way With Words](http://www.waywordradio.org/). If there's disagreement, they typically present both sides along with any relevant history, and let you decide your preference.

I think it would be useful to have an FAQ that describes the difference between standard and correct.

Answer (score 5):

From the provisional name of the proposal ("English language and **usage**"), I would expect that questions about usage *are* acceptable — and that's what these questions are: whether some usage is common, formal, regional, "correct", acceptable etc. This seems to be what is of most general interest, too. Aren't all usage questions "subjective"? Isn't it true that there's no "correct" or "incorrect" in grammar these days, and everything is determined by usage? :p

Comment: Agree I (me) grammar no incorrect right is. Usage subjective correct is. Language bigots upset all time get them hate I.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has a lot to do with deciding [who the audience of the site is](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/whos-the-audience-how-to-promote). It's my opinion that the site shouldn't be focused on matters of written style, especially punctuation. This is doubly compounded when all examples given are perfectly understandable, attested English. I think signaling the difference between grammaticality and written formal standards is far enough.

There are examples of style that are acceptable, though: for example, which sociolect or register to adopt in which situation.